# git push(or pull) along with local history

Tags: git, pull

I am a svn user and thought will try out git. I created a repository which would act like my central repository, a staging repo for testing and moving it to central repo and many clone of staging repo.  I made a few commits to the clone.

Now to make the commit history in that clone available in the staging repo I did

git pull --rebase

and now I have the changes as they happened on that clone.
Now you would wonder why I would want to do it. May be sometimes (or many times) one of the the small commits may have screwed up your software and it is easy for someone testing the staging repo to go back one small step rather than one sift through all the changes looking for the bug.
One thing that is stopping me from adopting git is the central or staging repo will have big jumps rather than incremental changes. The incremental changes happen in clones of the developers.
Is it the way DVCS works or have I got my arrangement wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be over complicating things with multiple repo's. I think your workflow would work using branches instead of repo's.

See: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  But still it's not quite clear to me. Say  a developer(based on the model you suggested) creates a branch from the develop branch and implements a new feature. When he merges back does it appear to some one who pulls this from the develop branch see it as one big chunk or as a series of commits as the developer commited. I did not understand the role of --no-ff flag.

Comment: A correction to my post above. When he merges back does it appear to some one who pulls this from the develop branch see it as one big chunk or as a series of commits as the developer commited "on his local branch"?

Comment: That depends on whether the developer has merged his changes into one change, or has pushed the complete series.

Comment: I asked this question because I screwed up while merging from one of the clones to the origin master and the history on the origin master got messed up. After some experiments now I got a hang of things and I am comfortable using git. Thanks for your time Peter